# Shiny app doesn't work after domain name change

Tags: r, server, shiny

I got a problem regarding Shiny app (or about the web server).

The app is hosted and works well here: http://shiny.eeb.ucla.edu/GermlineAtlas/

The web administrator point this site to a new domain: https://germline.mcdb.ucla.edu/

**It works in some devices (both Mac and Windows), but not mine (MacBook with Catalina 10.15.6).**

I tried open with Safari and Chrome, same error: [image: ShADED!]

It is shaded, I could switch between tab, but the buttons and reactions do not function.

Again it currently happen only on my machine...Hope you could give me some advice!!!!
Thanks,

Comment: Even the first link gives error: `An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.`  I am using Windows.  I do get the plot.

Comment: @YBS This is because of the input (choose Week_7_female and then SOX17 should have no error). I think it is a different problem with the second link.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...turn off my antivirus system.